# Testing mocked objects rhino mocks

Tags: nunit, rhino-mocks

I am new to RhinoMocks, and I am trying to write a test as shown
I have classes like these

```
public class A
{
    public void methodA(){}
}
public class B
{
    public void methodB(A a)
    {
      a.methodA();
    }
}
```

And i am trying to test it like this

```
A a = MockRepository.GenerateMock<A>();
public void ShouldTest()
{
    B b = new B();
    b.methodB(a);
    a.AssertWasCalled(x=>x.methodA());
    a.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

But it is giving the error as shown:
System.InvalidOperationException : No expectations were setup to be verified, ensure that the method call in the action is a virtual (C#) / overridable (VB.Net) method call.

How do I test methodB then?? Can someone help??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhino mock creates proxy class when you call `MockRepository.Generate ***` method. This means that it *extends* your type. If you don't declare any abstraction you cannot make any derivation which is essential in any mocking framework.

You can do two things

1. Create an interface (better design)
2. Make the member *virtual* (this will allow RhinoMocks to derive from your type and create a proxy for the virtual member

Sample code

```
public interface IA { void methodA();}
public class A:IA{public void methodA() { }}
public class B
{
    public void methodB(IA a)
    {
        a.methodA();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Bar
{
    [Test]
    public void BarTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var repo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IA>();

        //Act
        B b = new B();
        b.methodB(repo);

        //Assert
        repo.AssertWasCalled(a => a.methodA());
        repo.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have concrete classes with no virtual methods and no interfaces. You can't mock anything.

**Update:**

Here's one way to do it:

```
public interface IA
{
    void methodA();
}

public class A : IA
{
    public void methodA(){}
}
public class B
{
    public void methodB(IA a)
    {
      a.methodA();
    }
}
```

Then use

```
IA a = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IA>();
```

Comment: thumbs up :-) Forgot to make methodA virtual. Can u tell what does virtual mean in C# exactly?

Comment: It means it can be overridden in a derived class. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I'm a bit annoyed - I posted the code sample 5 minutes before @oleksii (and the basic answer well before that), yet his answer was accepted. Please reconsider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Will, i just liked the way other person explained the answer so accepted it, your answer was perfectly well.

Comment: @TrueWill I started writing the answer before there were any, but by the time I finished there was one (at that time w/o code sample so I still posted mine). Anyways you answer is good, so +1.